# Which is grammatically correct? "My test is the next day" or "My test is on next day"?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to know that whether both the sentence are same or one is wrong?
"My test is the next day" or "My test is on next day"?
I know perhaps it is a very basic question but still I want to know so please answer.

Comment: Yeah, actually I forgot to put "the" before the latter sentence but I had it in mind while I was writing. Anyway can you tell me if first sentence is right or wrong?

Comment: 'My test is on the following day' is fine, and preposition deletion with temporal prepositional phrases very common.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sorry but didn't get the point? I mean is it right to say "My test is the next day" as for me I think "on" should be used or I should use "tomorrow" instead of "next day". What do you think is right? I want to know if the first sentence is grammatically correct or not?

Comment: 'My test is the next day.' is grammatical, but would not be used instead of 'My test is tomorrow.'. 'My revision packet only arrives next Tuesday, and my test is the next day!' BUT NOT 'I have to revise this afternoon; my test is the next day.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say either

> My test is on the next day.

or

> My test is the next day.

Speakers of American English often drop the *on*.

As for tomorrow, you can say

> My test is tomorrow.

This month I heard an educated American speaker say something was happening *on tomorrow*, which surprises me; I don't know if British English speakers say that.

Comment: Thanks, understood.